# underscore is a valid seperator for number in js

Tags: javascript

Why javascript ignores `_` in the numbers?

like, `20_20 === 2020` is `true`.

It kinda makes sense, but also somehow it doesn't. I don't see any related contents/articles explaining this. How many browsers support this? Is this part of ECMAScript as standard?

Also, just for reference,

`parseInt("89_23")` returns you, `89`.

Comment: You could have a look at [this](https://v8.dev/features/numeric-separators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [new proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator) which just reached Stage 4 and is officially part of the standard.

You can see where it's supported on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#bcd:javascript.grammar) - most newer browsers support it, but older ones do not.

It's not safe to use in production yet - best to either use Babel to transpile your code (if you already have a build process that uses it), or avoid `_`s in numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it. but you have to be aware of the limitations. Here is the link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#bcd:javascript.grammar

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnHpL.png)